Lock classes and Threading in python for dict moifications
I was learning and testing threading in python, and Lock class, So in here I want to add a key to persons but let's say it will takes some time, in another thread I want to read the key. in first thread I should lock the process but I still get an error.
import threading
from time import sleep


persons = {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": "test2",
}
lock = threading.Lock()

def func1():
    global persons
    lock.acquire()
    sleep(10)
    persons["test3"] = "test3"
    lock.release()

def func2():
    global persons
    print(persons["test3"])

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()

I lock the func1() but still get error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\p.riahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Users\p.riahi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\p.riahi\Desktop\temp\thred.py", line 20, in func2
    print(persons["test3"])
          ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'test3'

Can anyone help me what I misunderstand here, the func1() should have locked the persons but it's not.

Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Why is there no lock.acquire() in func2()? btw since you are not assigning to persons you don't need global persons

From what I understand we lock the persons so I want to lock it when assigning a new value so that in those operations another thread could not read or write to it until it's unlocked, is there any reason why I need to lock in func2()?

Just a style note; If I was testing a dictionary, I would use different values for the keys and the dictionary entries just to make it absolutely clear that the test code was not erroneously mixing them up. E.g., persons["key3"]="person3".

If thread t2 runs before thread t1 acquires the lock and adds "test3", t2.join() might cause the main thread to wait for t2 to finish even though there's no "test3" key yet in the dictionary. This could lead to a KeyError exception.
So, you should lock the person inside function2 and release it after read the person. I have modified the code, you can use it.
import threading
from time import sleep


persons = {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": "test2",
}
lock = threading.Lock()

def func1():
    global persons
    lock.acquire()
    sleep(10)
    persons["test3"] = "test3"
    lock.release()

# def func2():
#     global persons
#     print(persons["test3"])
def func2():
    global persons
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        value = persons["test3"]  # Attempt to get the value
        print(value)
    except KeyError:  # Handle case where key doesn't exist
        print("Key 'test3' not found in the dictionary")
    finally:
        lock.release()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()


Hi, thanks for your time but this will not work in real-world and questions the real usage of threading, I don't want to block until the first function invokes. I just want to lock the person dict when the operation occur

Okay, then you can use lock inside function2 to prevent execution of function2 before function 1

The list persons and the lock are only loosely associated. There is no hard rule which binds the two. You need to take out the lock in the other function:
import threading
from time import sleep


persons = {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": "test2",
}
lock = threading.Lock()

def func1():
    lock.acquire()
    sleep(5)
    persons["test3"] = "test3"
    lock.release()

def func2():
    lock.acquire()
    print(persons["test3"])
    lock.release()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()

Output:
test3
Also note that there is a chance that t2 may actually start before t1, so you may need another mechanism for this to work in all cases.
